# Pass data into change event callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Using backbone.js - I want to bind an event to any change in the model and the collections/models that are nested inside it.

Right now I do an `@bind 'change', () ->` when initializing the base model.

How can I pass data on any change, even that of deep nested models? Does the change event carry variables with it? I need things like the model's collection, id, attributes, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the change event carry variables with it?

Yes, the `change` event gets two arguments: First, the model itself; second, the new attribute value. There are several methods available on the model that are aimed specifically at getting information *during* a `change` event. See the docs on [hasChanged](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-hasChanged), [changedAttributes](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-changedAttributes), [previous](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-previous), and [previousAttributes](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-previousAttributes).

So for instance, to access the previous attributes of a model each time it changes, you'd write

```
@bind 'change', (model) ->
  prevAttrs = model.previousAttributes()
  ...
```